# How many addressable bits are in 4 kilobytes of memory?

Tags: bitmap

I have come across the following statement in a solution for a problem:

> We have 4 kilobytes of memory which means we can address up to 8 * 4 * 2^10 bits.

Where is the 2^10 coming from? I would have thought that we could address 8 * 4 * 1000 bits.

For reference, the question is:

> You have an array with all the numbers from 1 to N, where N is at most
>   32000. The array may have duplicate entries and you do not know what N is. With only 4 kilobytes of memory available, how would you print all
>   duplicate elements in the array?

Comment: A kilobyte is 1024 bytes.  Each byte is 8 bits.  4 * 1024 * 8.  But 2 raised to the 10th power is 1024.

Comment: KB = 2^10 bytes. MB = 2^20 bytes. GB = 2^30 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 kilobyte is supposed to be 1000 bytes whereas 1 kibibyte is 2^10=1024.
However, kibi* and related units never really caught on, so "kilobyte" almost always means 1024 bytes in practice.